# How to prevent self password change in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I would like to stop the self password change. How to achieve this?

One database user should not be able to change his own password. I need to stop before changing this in MySQL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html: "Any client who connects to the server using a nonanonymous account can change the password for that account."

Comment: One question. Why?